# how to mount with udisks to specified directory

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, mount, mountpoint, udisks

I have ubuntu 12.04 and I need a **portable** solution (to work on various linux systems) and to **be in my user's home directory** for **mounting a partition after login or after boot**.

From what I searched on web I saw that using **udisks** is the best solution but what I did not find is how to mount the auxiliary partition to a specified mount point (directory path)

What I have so far is (by device name):

```
/usr/bin/udisks --mount /dev/sdbX
```

or (by uuid):

```
/usr/bin/udisks --mount /dev/disk/by-uuid/1313-F422
```

but there is no example on how to specify the mount point.

For me, it is mandatory to have a specific directory target (/media/AUX/ for example).

Is there a way to do this (not necessarily using udisks) ?

Answer (score 5):

udisks won't mount your partitions like this. Moreover if you want persistent mount I'd suggest to edit `/etc/fstab` to add:

```
UUID=YOUR_OWN_PARTITION_UUID /media/AUX/ ext4 defaults 0 0
```

**Note:** edit /etc/fstab using `sudo` as it requires root privileges

Then reboot to see your drive / partition properly mounted

Comment: Yes, this was my first choice, but the problem is the partition is mounted by root, and I will need to change the mountpoint dir rights, and also I have to create the mount point before rebooting. I would need the mount to create the mountpoint automaticaly with my user access rights.

Answer (score 0):

Not with udisks

If this is a USB connected device (portable solution), all you have to do is change the label on the disk to match what you want. (you can use gparted or Disk Utility for this for example). A USB connected drive/partition labelled AUX will automatically be mounted at /media/AUX.

Comment: @ungalcrys does the above meet your criterion? If not, why? I'd love to help

Comment: the portable solution refers to the script file or configuration needed to have the job done (mount the device to a specified directory) but not using the sudo and **preferably** changes must be in my home directory

Comment: @ungalcrys When reading your original question I find the statement "For me, it is mandatory to have a specific directory target (/media/AUX/ for example)." 1) sudo is not required for the answer I provided and 2) "preferably changes must be in my home directory" wasn't in the question. If it's mandatory to have access from your home directory, make a link to /media/AUX in your home directory. I hope this helps.

Comment: @ungalcrys Improve your question by specifying your criteria for an acceptable answer